# Find An Available (Idle) Map/Reduce Deployment

Tags: mapreduce, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Ok,

So, I'm trying to spread some heavy duty processing for incoming data across lots of Map/Reduce deployments. My question is, how can I find out which deployment is currently 'idle'? Further, reading the documentation, it appears I can 'submit' against the same deployment over and over, and achieve the same thing (I'll get a null, from the submit)? Is that true?

I understand that I could utilize the 'Scheduled Script Instance Search', but I cannot seem to be able to get it to return the 'idle' deployments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you schedule a task without defining the deployment, NetSuite allocates to the next available queue. Also you might be interested in this article if you're doing heavy processing: https://ursuscode.com/netsuite-tips/epic-battle-concurrent-map-reduce-vs-concurrent-suitelet/

Comment: when I do that, I get NO_DEPLOYMENTS_AVAILABLE

Comment: changing the script deployment from "scheduled" to "not scheduled" fixed it